# Attaching a json policy to a s3 bucket with CDK and typescript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-policies

I have a policy statement which I can add to my bucket:

```js
const statement = new PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    principals: '*',
    actions: ["s3:GetObject"],
    resources: [`${bucket.bucketArn}/*`],
});

mybucket.addToResourcePolicy(statement);
```

However, I have a policy document which contains multiple statements:

```js
 const policy = new PolicyDocument({
      statements: [// many statements ]
})
```

How can I attached this to my bucket?

Comment: Add multiple policy statements by calling `mybucket.addToResourcePolicy(...)` repeatedly?

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid, not the worst solution in the world, though. Will probably end up doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the policy document to a [CfnBucketPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.CfnBucketPolicy.html) construct:

```js
const cfnBucketPolicy = new s3.CfnBucketPolicy(this, 'MyCfnBucketPolicy', {
  bucket: bucket.bucketName,
  policyDocument: policy
});
```

Or apply each statement individually with `addToResourcePolicy`, as @jarmod suggets in the comments:

```js
declare const myStatements: iam.PolicyStatement[];
myStatements.forEach(bucket.addToResourcePolicy)
```

Comment: good solution but does not really cut down on much code. Will probably just add them individually.